# parse-server fails to start

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I have followed the commands below (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) to install parse server locally.

```
$ npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
$ mongodb-runner start
$ parse-server --appId myserver --masterKey myserver --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test
```

the server files are downloaded and stored at `~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/parse-server`.
when i try to run the 3rd command 
`parse-server --appId myserver --masterKey myserver --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test` on the terminal, I get the error below

```
parse-server: command not found
```

When i try to run `npm start` on the terminal from the same folder, I get the error below

```
parse-server@2.7.4 start /home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/parse-server
> node ./bin/parse-server

/home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:124
    const {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/index.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-112-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server@2.7.4 start: `node ./bin/parse-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server@2.7.4 start script 'node ./bin/parse-server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/parse-server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

how can i run it?
Another thing, I had already installed mongodb and was using it before trying to install parse-server on my laptop. did

```
npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
mongodb-runner start
```

install another mongo db on my laptop?

Comment: If you installed parse-server globally why do you need `node ./bin/parse-server` ?

Comment: Also, I don't use mongodb-runner, I just use `parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test`

Comment: @CodyG. `./bin/parse-server` is inside `parse-server` folder. I was trying to run `npm start` from inside the folder.

Comment: Does your parse-server command work outside of npm then? If not, try installing it again using `npm install parse-server -g` are you on windowS?

Comment: @CodyG. `parse-server` command doesn't work. I get the error `command not found`. I'm on Ubuntu. I'm following the instructions at https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server

Comment: What version of ubuntu? Yeah you shouldn't get the error `command not found` after installing it globally.

Comment: @CodyG. version 16.04

Comment: I would ensure you're using nvm (node version manager) to install node/npm and then try installing parse-server again, maybe try an earlier version of parse-server (i.e. 2.7.0) --- do you get any error messages when trying to install parse-server?

Comment: @CodyG. I solved the problem. check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by updating my `nodejs` version from `4.2.6` to `8.11.1` using the commands below

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

After that, I added parse-server path to `/etc/enviroment` file

```
sudo gedit /etc/enviroment
```

appended this line `:~/.npm-global/bin`
then I run `source /etc/enviroment` command
and was able to start parse-server from the terminal

```
parse-server --appId myserver --masterKey myserver --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test
```